# После загрузки страницы ошибка NetworkError

Tags: javascript, jquery, сеть

Еще раз здравствуйте, после загрузки страницы в консоль вываливается такая вот ошибка "NetworkError: A network error occurred." и говорит что источник вообще где то в файле jquery.min.js выглядит это вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так посмотрите в мониторе сети откуда NetworkError-то

Comment: Вы так говорите как будто я каждый день пользуюсь "монитором сети" и знаю что это такое, будьте добры поясните детальнее.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev вкладка `Сеть` в консоли, там найдите, что вызывает и что падает